# Well-posedness of the linear parabolic equations with respect to the inhomogeneous term as well as the initial data

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, linear-pde, regularity, cauchy-problem

I already asked the question on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821416/if-partial-t-u-n-delta-u-n-f-n-partial-t-u-delta-u-f-and-f-n-to), and have tried to figure it out myself.

But the problem seems trickier than expected, so I guess MO is a better place to ask..

For the sake of completeness, I repeat the question.

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let us consider the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u_n -\Delta u_n = f_n \text{ on } [0,T] \times \mathbb{T}^m \text{ with } u_n(t=0,x)=u^{0}_n(x)
\end{equation}
where $f_n(t,x) \in L^p_t\bigl( [0,T], L^q_x(\mathbb{T}^m) \bigr)$ for some fixed $p,q \in (1,\infty)$ and $u^{0}_n(x) \in W^{2,q}(\mathbb{T}^m)$. $T \in (0,\infty)$ is assumed to be fixed and $\mathbb{T}^m=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^m$ is the $m$-torus.

Then, it is well-known that there exists a unique weak solution, denoted as $u_n(t,x)$ for the above Cauchy problem.

Now, suppose that $u^{0}_n \to u^0$ in $W^{2,q}(\mathbb{T}^4)$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^p_t\bigl( [0,T], L^q_x(\mathbb{T}^m) \bigr)$. Denote by $u(t,x)$ the unique weak solution of the Cauchy problem
\begin{equation}
\partial_t u -\Delta u = f \text{ on } [0,T] \times \mathbb{T}^m \text{ with } u(t=0,x)=u^0(x)
\end{equation}

My question is that, do we have
\begin{equation}
u_n \to u \text{ in } W^{1,p}_t\bigl([0,T], L^q_x(\mathbb{T}^m) \bigr) \text{ as } n \to \infty?
\end{equation}

I strongly suspect so, but cannot find a way to prove using maximal regularity or well-posedness. Could anyone please help me?

Comment: I am confused, when you say, "it is well-known that there exists a unique weak solution [...] for the above Cauchy problem", how can you have that not but not a stability estimate w.r.t. to the data (and a suitable function space for the solution)?

Comment: @Hannes OK, I took the definition of a weak solution as well as equivalence to a mild solution for granted....I will add the details soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to make it correct for future reference.

You might want to look into this expository paper on maximal regularity for linear parabolic equations:
[https://people.math.ethz.ch/~salamon/PREPRINTS/parabolic.pdf](https://people.math.ethz.ch/%7Esalamon/PREPRINTS/parabolic.pdf)

Then, if you had an estimate of the form
$$\|u_n\|_{W^{1,p}_t(L^q_x)} \le C\left(\|u_{n,0}\|_{W^{2,q}} + \|f_n\|_{L^p(L^q)}\right),$$

for the same price, using that the equation is linear, you could use that
$$\|u_n - u_m\|_{W^{1,p}_t(L^q_x)} \le C\left(\|u_{n,0} - u_{m,0}\|_{W^{2,q}} + \|f_n - f_m\|_{L^p(L^q)}\right),$$
and thus you have a Cauchy sequence.

Note that $W^{2,q}$ is enough initial regularity to carry over, the optimal space is a Besov (check it in the link), but you can have the same kind of estimate with a more restrictive class.

I don't think you are going to have a stability/convergence result without having some existence + quantitative estimate.

Comment: I set the initial data to be quite regular on purpose, so that maximal regularity can be carried out with $\lVert u^0_n \rVert_{W^{2,q}}$. Then, it seems quite clear that your argument works with $\lVert u^0_n - u^0 \rVert_{W^{2,q}}$! Thank you for your insights!